# IndexError: list index out of range при использовании Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, requests, scrapy

Пытаюсь написать простенького паука чтобы вытащить данные с [сайта](http://www.voiceoveruniverse.com/). Задача такова - собрать имя и адрес персонального сайта в сети для каждого из зарегистрированных пользователей.

Структура сайта: плитками кликабельные участники, из информации только имя, чтобы получить адрес сайта мне надо зайти в анкету каждого участника и выйти обратно. Переход по страницам исходного сайта, т.е. перелистывание пользователей работает реализовано и работает успешно. С XPath и CSS селекторами вроде проблем нет, проходит все проверки, но паук отказывается работать. Получаю адрес страницы очередного пользователя, делаю запрос на этот URL, обрабатывается он отдельной функцией, которая должна парсить и имя и ссылку. Однако они не выводятся, вместо этого Scrapy падает с ошибкой. Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть?

```
from scrapy.http import Request, Response, HtmlResponse
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.htmlparser import             HtmlParserLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class VuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "vu2"

    allowed_domains = ["voiceoveruniverse.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.voiceoveruniverse.com/profiles/members/']


    def parse(self, response):
        base_url = 'http://voiceoveruniverse.com'
        SET_SELECTOR = 'div.member_item'
        for actor in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h5 a ::text'
            URL_SELECTOR = 'h5 a ::attr(href)'
            PROFILE_URL = base_url+actor.css(URL_SELECTOR)[0].extract()

            yield scrapy.Request(
                PROFILE_URL,
                callback=self.parse_item
        )

       # yield {
          #  'name': actor.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first()



        #}

        NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href'
        next_page = response.xpath(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
           'name':response.xpath('//dl/dt/span/text()')[0].extract(),

           'URL':response.xpath('//dd/a/@href')[-1].extract()

           }
```

Сама ошибка:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
2017-01-09 17:37:50 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://voiceoveruniverse.com/profile/NathanCole?xg_source=profiles_memberList> (referer: http://www.voiceoveruniverse.com/profiles/friend/list?page=3&xg_source=profiles_memberList_top_next)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/igor/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/igor/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/igor/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/igor/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/igor/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/igor/Загрузки/UpWork/vu2/vu2/spiders/vu2.py", line 46, in parse_item
    'name':response.xpath('//dl/dt/span/text()')[0].extract(),
  File "/home/igor/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 58, in __getitem__
    o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
```

Comment: Селекторы проверяю в консоли Scrapy. Все работает как ожидается.

Answer (score 0):

а все дело было не в неправильных селекторах xpath. Всего то надо было вместо  `base_url = 'http://voiceoveruniverse.com'` сделать  `base_url = 'http://www.voiceoveruniverse.com'`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что ваш паук наследует класс CrawlSpider, а в таком случае нельзя использовать метод parse который использует сам паук по умолчанию: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html.
Вам надо либо использовать класс Spider или переименовать метод parse.
Переменную base_url можно полностью удалить а для создания правильного линка использовать response.urljoin().Например

`URL_SELECTOR = 'h5 a ::attr(href)'
 PROFILE_URL = base_url+actor.css(URL_SELECTOR)[0].extract()`

можно переписать как

```
LINK = actor.css('h5 a ::attr(href)').extract()[0]
PROFILE_URL = response.urljoin(LINK)
```

Вам стоит прочитать базовый туториал на офф.сайте
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html там есть наглядные примеры по созданию простых пауков.